# Refacting Model (DRY) with score_increments for an internet game

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently built an online game and was wondering how I can refactor the code below to keep it DRY.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
before_create :game_score

def game_score
   level_one_a(kills)
   level_one_b(kills)
end

def self.level_one_a(kills)
    if kills >= 600
        increment!(:score, by = 6)
    elseif kills >= 500
        increment!(:score, by = 5)
    elseif kills >= 400
        increment!(:score, by = 4)
    end
end

def self.level_one_b(kills)
    if kills >= 550
        increment!(:score, by = 6)
    elseif kills >= 390
        increment!(:score, by = 5)
    elseif kills >= 348
        increment!(:score, by = 4)
    elseif kills >= 234
        increment!(:score, by = 3)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LEVEL_ONE_KILLS_INCREMENT = {
                             :a => {600 => 6, 500 => 5, 400 => 4},
                             :b => {550 => 6, 390 => 5, 348 => 4, 234 => 3}
                            }

def self.level_one(kills, type)
  LEVEL_ONE_KILLS_INCREMENT[type].keys.each do |key|
     increment!(:score, by = LEVEL_ONE_KILLS_INCREMENT[type][key]) if kills >= key
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Should the third to the last line have LEVEL_ONE_KILLS_INCREMENT rather than LEVEL_ONE_KILLS?

Comment: Yes, modified my answer